Making a join based on the latest day of the joining table
I have a simple order table in my postgres db and I want to join from a table of payments to create a new column for each order where the latest payment is indicated.
Each payment row looks like this:



id
order_id
status
date




1
1
paid
2024-04-08 16:34:09.860634+02



And if there are more payments to the same order, how can I assign the latest payment (based on date, or id, or simply the latest in the sequence) to the given order row? Some orders might be refunded, therefore I want to take the latest record that has refunded status and append it to the order.

Seems similar to one of my questions. Please see this SO answer and the question from which it arose. Perhaps you can adjust it to fit your use case. It's for MySQL / MariaDB, but I think it can be applied to PostgreSQL .

You can use DISTINCT ON. For example:
select distinct on (o.id) o.*, p.payment_date as last_payment_date
from ordert o
left join payment p on p.order_id = o.id
order by o.id, p.payment_date desc;

Result:
 id  buyer_id  order_date           last_payment_date        
 --- --------- -------------------- ------------------- 
 1   12        2024-04-01 12:34:56  2024-04-02 11:22:49 
 2   1         2024-01-11 22:33:44  2024-04-01 15:36:27 
 3   2         2024-02-11 20:23:24  null                

See running example at db<>fiddle.

After adjusting the query which I had linked to in the comments, I came up with the following. I have used DB Fiddle to provide a testing ground.

Table orders - columns and naming conventions are just for testing, you would use your normal table schema and your usual way of naming columns.



order_id
order_buyer_id
order_date




1
12
2024-04-01 12:34:56


2
1
2024-01-11 22:33:44


3
2
2024-02-11 20:23:24



Table payments - like above.



payment_id
payment_order_id
payment_status
payment_date




1
1
status 1
2024-04-01 13:52:19


2
2
status 2
2024-02-02 11:51:19


3
1
status 3
2024-04-02 11:22:49


4
2
status 4
2024-02-15 10:41:19


5
2
status 5
2024-03-22 08:53:36


6
2
status 6
2024-04-01 15:36:27




The query below extracts the latest payment, since you mentioned:

the latest payment (based on date, or id, or simply the latest in the sequence)

Other ways could be used - you would just target that particular column, instead of the date (which I'm doing in the query).
SELECT
    tmpDate.order_id,
    tmpDate.order_buyer_id,
    payments.payment_id,
    payments.payment_date,
    payments.payment_status
FROM payments
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        MAX(payments.payment_date) AS maxDate,
        orders.order_id,
        orders.order_buyer_id
    FROM payments
    INNER JOIN orders
        ON payments.payment_order_id = orders.order_id
    WHERE payments.payment_date > '0001-01-01 00:00:00'
    AND payments.payment_date IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY orders.order_id, orders.order_buyer_id
) tmpDate
    ON payments.payment_date = tmpDate.maxDate
    AND payments.payment_order_id = tmpDate.order_id
ORDER BY 
    payments.payment_date DESC,
    payments.payment_order_id ASC


Output
Schema (PostgreSQL v10)



order_id
order_buyer_id
payment_id
payment_date
payment_status




1
12
3
2024-04-02T11:22:49.000Z
status 3


2
1
6
2024-04-01T15:36:27.000Z
status 6




View on DB Fiddle
